# Where is the detailed documentation for the experimental Gradle with NDK support for Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, gradle-experimental

Where is the actual documentation for the experimental Gradle with NDK support for Android Studio? I mean the documentation with a full list of settings supported in the Gradle config, the list of releases with changes, etc...

After extensive Googling, all that I could find was these 2 pages, which are very superficial:

- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/android-ndk-preview
- http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

Comment: There is no official documentation for the experimental plugin, but people find many interesting features by digging through its published [sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle-experimental)

Answer (score 1):

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental is the official documentation, and will very likely be the only documentation until the plugin stops being "experimental."

This isn't an ideal situation, but it's pretty common for beta software. I've worked for several years alongside the tech writing team at Google, and I've learned that good tech writers are a scarce resource. They don't usually work on pre-release software, because anything they write would likely get invalidated by the next release.